# How do I Synchronize Timer.Elapsed with my WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, timer, synchronization

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode.PerSession,
    UseSynchronizationContext=false,
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
class IMyService : IMyService
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer;
    ....

    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // I want to arrive here on the service thread
    }
}
```

The parameters for my service are as above.

I am using a System.Timers.Timer within some service state object and I want the Timer.Elapsed event to fire back on the service thread. With a SynchronizationContext I can achieve this with this method:

```
context.Post(SendOrPostCallback callback, object state)
```

I can put that inside the Timer.Elapsed event and callback will be called on the service thread which is what I want.

Without SynchronizationContext I apparently need to set Timer.SynchronizingObject with an ISynchronizeInvoke object so that elapsed events are marshalled accordingly. But where do I get the ISynchronizeInvoke object from in a WCF service? Does it have one?

Comment: Are you getting any exception because I do not think you need to call methods on the service thread. WCF Services use Multi Threaded Apartment and thus the service object is not as such bound to any specific thread.

Comment: Yes I am getting exceptions. If a service operation is accessing a variable while the same variable is being accessed in the Timer.Elapsed handler that is not good.

Comment: Can you copy the exception here which exception is coming?

Comment: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. That's the error but it's not relevant, it's a threading issue that is hard to reproduce. A variable is being modified while in use by another thread so I need the Timer.Elapsed handler to run on the same thread that all the service operation do.

Comment: This is not because of thread affinity or thread's STA or MTA nature. The collection is getting modified somewhere while being in loop. You will need to analyze your code to not modify the collection while enumerating it.

Comment: No that's nothing to do with it, it's a threading issue, the collection is being looped in one thread and modified in another.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18495/discussion-between-freddy-flares-and-jags)